# Getting name spaced models inside Django 1.7 migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7, django-migrations

I'm using django-allauth as part of a new project, and I'm trying to make a migration where I set up the initial authentication keys for the social apps.

To do this I need to access a model that is under a namespace of

'allauth.socialaccount', which I also have in my settings.py

However, when I attempt to do the following;

`SocialApp = apps.get_model('allauth.socialaccount', 'socialapp')`

I end up with Django telling me the app with that name doesn't exist.

I have also tried pretty much every combination of 'allauth', 'socialaccount' and, 'socialapp'

I'm pretty much stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

For namespaced models you need to use the final part of the dotted path as the `app_label`. For `allauth.socialaccount` that is `socialaccount`.

```python
>>> apps.get_model('socialaccount', 'SocialApp')
allauth.socialaccount.models.SocialApp
```

Also don't forget to reference the a migration from the `socialaccount` app as a dependency, otherwise it won't be available:

```python
dependencies = [
    # ('some_app', 'XXXX_some_pre-requisite_migration'),
    ('socialaccount', '0001_initial'),
]
```